# Select syntax issue related to ;

Tags: sql-server

```
select count(*) from 
(select distinct acceptor_id, requestor_id from request_accepted);
```

When I am running the above, am getting the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 541
Incorrect syntax near ';'
```

Any suggestions. Am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You need an alias to the subquery, like:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct acceptor_id, requestor_id from request_accepted) as subQuery;
```